# Question on Inverse of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inverse-function

Let's consider $f:A\to B$. I thought that if we find another function $g$ such that

$f\circ g=id$ and $g\circ f =id$ then $g$ is the inverse function of $f$ (and vice versa).

However, our tutor said that this isn't true without further explaining why...

What am I missing? There must be a detail I don't see...Maybe someone has an example?

Comment: You are correct.  For many that is the *definition* of $f$ being invertible with inverse $g$.   This is equivalent to $f$ being bijective.

Comment: You should specify that $g$ maps $B$ to $A$, and the identity maps should specified as $id_B$ and $id_A$, respectively.  With those clarifications, your asssertion is correct.

Comment: @quasi, Ahh ok I think that's the problem: \begin{align*}
&f:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+, \text{ where } f(x):=x^2\\
&g:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}, \text{ where } g(y):=\sqrt{y}\\
&\implies (g\circ f)(x) =|x|=x\text{ and } (f\circ g)(y)=y.
\end{align*}
However, the inverse function of $f$ is $h:\mathbb{R}_+\to\underline{\mathbb{R}_+}$ mit $h(x):=\sqrt{y}$

Comment: @Randall, no it's not. See my comment.

Comment: @Philipp: My proposed clarifications were intended as just that -- clarifications, but they are not actually necessary; identity functions are bijective functions from a set to itself, so the specifications I suggested are already implied. In particular, regarding your proposed counterexample, the composition $g\circ f$ is not actually an identity function. So Randall is correct. Sorry if my initial comment misled you.

Comment: @quasi why is $g\circ f $ not an identity function? It maps from $\mathbb{R}_+$ to  $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: @Philipp: No. Based on your definitions, $g\circ f$ maps $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @quasi, so strictly speaking in my example $f\circ g $ is not well defined because the codomain of $g$ is not a subset of the domain of $f$?

Comment: @Philipp: Strictly speaking, yes, since you explicitly specified the domains and codomains. In fact, strictly speaking, for $f \circ g$ to be well defined, the codomain of $g$ must be the _same_ as the domain of $f$. In practice, we are usually less strict. Typically we allow implicit restrictions needed to allow compositions to work, but in doing so, we are actually implicitly defining _new_ functions.

Comment: @Philipp  I was assuming that you knew that $g$ had to map $g:B \to A$ (otherwise your identity claims make no sense).

Comment: @Philipp: Bottom line (as in my initial comment) -- when dealing with inverse functions and identity functions, to avoid confusion, I would explicitly specify the domains and codomaisns.